# callback c delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, callback

This is procedure which is defined in C++ application (exe HOST).

```
typedef struct _ RX_DATA_OBJ {
   UINT32     TIME;        
   UINT32     ID;    
   UINT8      LEN; 
   UINT8      DATA[8]; 
} RX_DATA_OBJ;

static void RX_DATA(UINT16 CNT, RX_DATA_OBJ *p_RX_DTATA_OBJ)
```

I need to call as callback above function in my DLL file written in Delphi.

I made the following declaration in Delphi for my DLL:

```
type
  TRX_DATA_OBJ = record
    time: UINT32;
    id:   UINT32;
    len:  UINT8;
    data: array [0..7] of UINT8;
  end;
  PRX_DATA_OBJ = ^TRX_DATA_OBJ;

RX_DATA = procedure(count:UINT16; RX_DATA_OBJ: PRX_DATA_OBJ ) of object;

var
  RX_DATA_out: TRX_DATA_OBJ;
```

In another procedure I get the pointer to the  RX_DATA procedure in HOST.
Now I call this callback in my DLL

```
procedure PUT_DATA;
begin
  RX_DATA_out.Time := 100;
  RX_DATA_out.id := $500;
  RX_DATA_out.len := 4;
  RX_DATA_out.data[0] := 1;
  RX_DATA_out.data[1] := 2;
  RX_DATA_out.data[2] := 3
  RX_DATA_out.data[3] := 4;
  RX_DATA_out.data[4] := 5;
  RX_DATA_out.data[5] := 6;
  RX_DATA_out.data[6] := 7;
  RX_DATA_out.data[7] := 8;

  RX_DATA(1, @RX_DATA_out); // RX_DATA_out is global variable defined.
end;
```

Callback is called correct but data passed  in RX_DATA_out variable are not correct, it looks that pointer to  RX_DATA_out variable is not pointing on this variable.

Can anybody say what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

The C++ function type is a plain function, i.e. not a member function. But you have declared your version to be a method of object. That is a mismatch. You must remove `of object`.

You must also specify the calling convention. Most likely it will be `cdecl`. In Delphi, if the calling convention is not specified, then the register based Delphi fastcall convention, `register` is used. That's certainly wrong.

Finally, if the pointer to the struct can never be `nil` then it is more idiomatic to use a `var` parameter:

```
RX_DATA = procedure(count:UINT16; var RX_DATA_OBJ: TRX_DATA_OBJ); cdecl;
```

And obviously you'd have to change the calling code to match:

```
RX_DATA(1, RX_DATA_out);
```

Comment: When I use cdecl; it hangs-on c++ HOST application

Comment: when I put var as You suggest I cannot compile my code 
I have error in RX_DATA(1,@RX_DATA_out);

Comment: Of course you do. You naturally have to change the calling code too! Remove the `@`. As for calling convention, you need to find out what  calling convention  the C++ code expects. And use that in your Delphi code.

Comment: It still does not work, HOST is hang-on. It is only corect calling when is of object but then data are not correct :(

Comment: How did you find out what calling convention to use?

Comment: c++ expect cdecl that I know but when I'm doing as You suggest is still not working

Comment: because I have description that all conversion in functions must be used cdcel. And other functions which are implemented in my DLL are called correct by HOST using cdcel

Comment: My answer is accurate given the information in the question. Did you omit anything, or transcribe it incorrectly? For example, `RX_DATA` in the C++ code is not a function pointer type. It's the declaration of a function. Surely there's a function pointer type declared somewhere. You didn't show that.

Comment: This is given in the description for programmer who must writen dll and call callback function
typedef void (CALLBACKATTR *RD_DATA_OBJ_HDLR)( UINT16 count,
RD_DATA_OBJ FAR * p_obj);

Comment: this declaration in source code I got from author of HOST application :
static void RX_DATA(UINT16 CNT, RX_DATA_OBJ *p_RX_DTATA_OBJ)

Comment: What does `CALLBACKATTR` evaluate to?

Comment: There is information that pointer to this callback function is passed as a variable in the function called in DLL, and it is ok becase I call this callback correctbut using this pointer but only when I use  'of object'
There is nothing more written about it.

Comment: We are going round in circles. My answer is correct given the information you have provided. Trial and error is a hopeless way to program. Your function pointer is clearly not `of object`. I've no idea why you think that it is.

Comment: additional there is information that if there is no any data to pass then call this callback with null (nil)

Comment: Because it is called correct when I use 'of object', I mean that HOST is not hangs-on and display data passed via callback but this data are not what I sent to HOST.

Comment: Most likely the interop is fine when you remove `of object` and include `cdecl`. But the callback fails for some other reason, a reason outside the scope of the question that you asked.